# F# pattern matching problem?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, type-inference

I have a problem when pattern matching with F#. I'm building an F# library and have this so far:

```
namespace parser
    module parse =
        let public y = function 
        | x when x.Contains("hi") -> "HELLO" 
        | x when x.Contains("hello") -> "HI" 
        | x -> x
```

but it gives me error: Error    Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.

Comment: See also http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2009/10/25/overview-of-type-inference-in-f/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essentially, the compiler doesn't understand that you want the argument to your function to be of type `string`. Basically, you can NOT invoke instance methods on implicitly declared function arguments. You'll need to use something like the following.

```
let y (value:string) = 
  match value when
  | x when x.Contains("hi") -> "HELLO" 
  | x when x.Contains("hello") -> "HI" 
  | x -> x
```

Interestingly, if you were not invoking an instance method, but instead using it in some other way (where the type was already known), you would be fine. In other words, suppose a `StringUtils` module contained a method `Has`, which took in two strings and performed the same check as `Contains`; if so, you *could* use the implicit argument, because the compiler already knows of which type the value must be.

```
  module StringUtils =
    let has (word:string) value = word.Contains(value)

  module Parse =
    let y = function 
     | x when x |> StringUtils.has "hi" -> "HELLO" 
     | x when x |> StringUtils.has "hello" -> "HI" 
     | x -> x
```

Obviously, in many cases, this sort of thing is unnecessarily verbose. But it demonstrates the larger point about F#'s type inference behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler wants to know the type of `x` is in your `y` function so you need to annotate it, like this:

```
let y (x: string) =
  match x with
  | x when x.Contains "hi" -> "HELLO"
  | x when x.Contains "hello" -> "HI"
  | x -> x
```